# Error message in Http request

Tags: java

I am using the code below to make http request but when exception is thrown I am not able to fetch error message per field. In postman it does show proper error message:

```
   HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    con.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    con.setDoOutput(true);


    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic KEY")
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length()));
    try {
        con.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
         stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();


        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        println stringBuffer.toString()
        throw new Exception("Some error occurred " + e.message)
    }
```

It simply shows the message "`Server returned HTTP response code: 422 for URL: https://test.api.promisepay.com/users/35`"

Whereas in Postman it shows:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "mobile": [
            "already exists"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: did you copy that from Postman?

Comment: or send your postman's request picture

Comment: what is the output of the code, does it execute try block or ends up with catching exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read error using input stream instead you should use error stream for that purpose.

Below is an example snippet :

After writing data to output stream you should check what response code has been returned :

**int respCode = con.getResponseCode();**

Then check whether response code returned is 200 or not, if it is not then there has been some error :

```
InputStream is=null;
 if(respCode==200){
    is = con.getInputStream();                    
 } else if (urlConnection.getErrorStream() != null) {
    is = con.getErrorStream();
 }
```

Now you can change your code for reading the error :

```
final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(is));
stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
   stringBuffer.append(line);
}
rd.close();
```

Hope this may help!

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.